# How to exclude custom post type Tag from the loop?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to get all categories of custom post type `"Services"` with relative posts, but its showing tags also and I want to exclude the services taxonomy tags from the category list. Sorry I'm stuck on it to solve the issue. Please can someone help me to solve it?

```
<?php
$post_type = 'services';
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( array( 'post_type' => $post_type,  ) );
 
foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) :
 
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
 
    foreach( $terms as $term ) : ?>

        <?php
        $args = array(
                'post_type' => $post_type,
                'posts_per_page' => -1,  //show all posts
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $term->slug,
                    )
                    
                )
 
            );
        $posts = new WP_Query($args);
 
        if( $posts->have_posts() ): ?> 
        <section class="mb-5 pb-5">
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center mb-5">
        <h2 class="h4"><?php echo $term->name; ?></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <?php while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
        

        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 mb-3 mb-lg-0">
          <div class="card card-style-1 shadow-lg border-0 text-center">
          <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink();?>" class="position-absolute top-0 bottom-0 w-100 h-100"></a>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="card-title">
              <h3 class="h6 fw-normal"><?php echo the_title(); ?></h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>      
                    
        <?php endwhile; 
       ?>
       </div>
       </div>
</section>

       <?php
      endif; ?>
 
    <?php endforeach;
 
endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$post_type = 'services';
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( array( 'post_type' => $post_type,  ) );
$exclude = array( 'post_tag' );
 
foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) :

    if( in_array( $taxonomy->name, $exclude ) ) {
            continue;
    }

 
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
 
    foreach( $terms as $term ) : ?>

        <?php
        $args = array(
                'post_type' => $post_type,
                'posts_per_page' => -1,  //show all posts
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $term->slug,
                    )
                    
                )
 
            );
        $posts = new WP_Query($args);
 
        if( $posts->have_posts() ): ?> 
        <section class="mb-5 pb-5">
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center mb-5">
        <h2 class="h4"><?php echo $term->name; ?></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <?php while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
        

        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 mb-3 mb-lg-0">
          <div class="card card-style-1 shadow-lg border-0 text-center">
          <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink();?>" class="position-absolute top-0 bottom-0 w-100 h-100"></a>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="card-title">
              <h3 class="h6 fw-normal"><?php echo the_title(); ?></h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>      
                    
        <?php endwhile; 
       ?>
       </div>
       </div>
</section>

       <?php
      endif; ?>
 
    <?php endforeach;
 
endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Not working brother

Comment: @Devbuddy Did you paste your taxnomy names for exclude to array $exclude = array( );  ?

Comment: No bro, I just paste your code. Actually I want to remove all tags not a specific tags with name in array. is that possible?

Comment: can I get any solutions?

Comment: @Devbuddy tag is a taxonomy. You need to know the name in order to exclude it